# jQuery event click when clicked on any content inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery:

```
$("div.result").live("click", function(event){
alert("kokoko");
});
```

HTML could be:

```
<div id="result">
Flash banner code
Image with link 
etc.
</div>
```

What I want to do is to trigger the alert when any of the elements inside the div holder is clicked on. Currently the alert is not trigger when there is a image banner inside result.

Comment: How is the image banner included? If it is included by an `iframe`, the click will not be registered (indeed, *cannot* be registered if the `iframe` is served from another domain). This includes most Javascript systems.

Comment: So there is no solution with JS if it is a iframe from another domain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#result").on("click", function(){
    alert("kokoko");
});

// or

$("#result").click(function(){
    alert("kokoko");
});

// or just pure JavaScript

document.getElementById("result").addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert("kokoko");
});
```

Though it's a good practice to solve cross-browser issues with pure JavaScript like this (with `addEvent` and `removeEvent` functions):

```
(function(){
    if ( document.addEventListener ) {
        this.addEvent = function(elem, type, fn) {
            elem.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
            return fn;
        };

        this.removeEvent = function(elem, type, fn) {
            elem.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
        };
    } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
        this.addEvent = function(elem, type, fn) {
            var bound = function() {
                return fn.apply(elem, arguments);
            };
            elem.attachEvent("on" + type, bound);
            return bound;
        };

        this.removeEvent = function (elem, type, fn) {
            elem.detachEvent("on" + type, fn);
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: Sometimes I am just blind.

Comment: @Railsbeginner Nothing to mention , everything is happening :)

Answer (score 5):

Never use or recommend [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which is deprecated...

```
$("#result").on("click", function(event){
alert("kokoko");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$("#result").on("click", function(){
    alert("it worked!");
});
```

live is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

should be div#result .result would be a class. Also, try not to use live, use .on() instead.