# Javascript if div is clicked or any a tag clicked then

Tags: javascript

I am currently using the below to detect if an element with the id `bar` is clicked. I would like to change it so that this function would run whether `bar` is clicked or any `a` tag without duplicating the function.

```
document.getElementById("bar").onclick = function() {
    //do things...
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217766/jquery-event-click-when-clicked-on-any-content-inside-a-div/14217780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the function separately and give it a name:

```
function MyFunction() {
    // Your function here
}

document.getElementById("bar").onclick = MyFunction;

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = MyFunction;
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` returns a list of `a` tags used in your code.  So you have to iterate it.

Comment: I accidentally hit submit before I was finished. The post was already edited. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for assuming, but no, it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browsers you can target, you could use

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#bar, a");
for (var i=0, ii=nodes.length; i < ii; i++) {
    nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function multiElementClickHandler(event){ alert("clicked " + event.target); });
}
```

Otherwise, define it separately like @mayabelle said. :)

Comment: If you're going to suggest `.addEventListener` (which is of course better than `.onclick`) it would be worth mentioning the possible need of `.attachEvent` for browser compatibility. +1 anyway though

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was thinking querySelectorAll was IE 9 and later, but it looks like this particular query would be supported in IE 8 and that attachEvent would be needed there as well.